# Set PCB size with values altium

Tags: altium

I've been searching for a way to set PCB size in Altium, I can change size using Mouse, but there is no way I found to change it to some values using keyboard.

Like I want to change PCB size to 10" x 1.5" but I can't unless I use Edit Vertices and move the edges.

I read the documentation, but there is nothing in there about specific size.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 8):

You can define the board size from a primitive, for example, draw the edges of the board using lines, select them all, then go to Desing->Board Shape->Define from selected objects:

[image]

Another way is using the PCB Board Wizard. You need the File menu on your side panel:

[image]

[image]

Then use the PCB Board Wizard where you can define the exact board size along with other parameters. If you don't have the File menu you can show it going to View->Workspace Panels->System->Files.

Answer (score 1):

It may have changed a bit, the version we're using is a bit different from @ Andres:

[image]

If you do Design->Board Shape->Redefine Board shape you can draw the outline with straight lines (easier if you turn snap on first to get the mm or mils exactly even).

If it's some odd size or has lines that are curved you might be better to use 'define from objects'. Draw lines, arcs etc. (say on a mechanical layer), get them right and make sure the outline is **closed** (you can adjust the lengths and positions by double clicking and entering the numbers) and then select all of them, and use Define from selected objects.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a layer called "BOARD_OUTLINE" (I generally use Mechanical Layer 6) and I set the grid to the greatest common factor of the desired board length and width. For example, if I want a 10.5mm x 4.0mm board, the greatest common factor would be 0.5mm. Then on the BOARD_OUTLINE layer I would draw an outline using the snap grid and the HUD to get the right length and width. Once the outline is complete I would use the keyboard shortcut E-S-Y for "**E**dit --> **S**elect --> All on La**y**er" and then the shortcut D-S-D for "**D**esign --> Board **S**hape --> **D**efine from Selected Objects".

If you want to set the length and width just by typing in the numbers, however, the board wizard is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can import a DWG/DXF file to Altium and then 'Redefine board shape' to have a better board sizing and layout. Though you need CAD software to create a DWG/DXF file, it's still good for complex board shapes.